# Why is Python looking for Python37.zip under the Anaconda3 folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, path, discord.py

My Discord bot doesn't even start running when I debug it but gives the following error instantly on pressing F5:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip'
```

The traceback is all 'not-my-code' and comes down to a `def exists(path):` function in Python module `genericpath.py`:

```
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
```

If it seems that is not the full traceback, here is the VSCode call stack:

[image]

It doesn't even get to the first `import` in the `bot.py` startup file, yet when I run it *without debugging*, it seems to work fine and is no worse off for not finding `python37.zip`. I doubt there would be a `.zip` file in there anyway, and I have made no recent changes in the Anaconda folder. This problem seemed to just appear after I added a new DAL function that isn't even called anywhere.

For the record, my `bot.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import common
from notes_cog import NotesCommands
from misc_cog import MiscCommands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from books_cog import BooksCommands
from notes_cog import NotesCommands
from misc_cog import MiscCommands
from dal import get_prefixes

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

async def _prefix_callable(bot, message):
    """ 
    Determines the list of command prefixes for the current guild
    """
    prefList = []
    if message.guild:
        prefList = get_prefixes(message.guild.id)
        if prefList is None:
            prefList = common.DEFAULT_PREFIXES
        else:
            prefList.extend(prefList.split(";"))
    else:
        prefList.extend(common.DEFAULT_PREFIXES)
    print(prefList)
    return prefList

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=_prefix_callable, name=common.BOT_NAME, description=f"{common.BOT_NAME}. Your note taking bot.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.add_cog(NotesCommands(bot))
bot.add_cog(BooksCommands(bot))
bot.add_cog(MiscCommands(bot))
bot.help_command.cog = bot.cogs["Notes Commands"]

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: @jakub Those three lines are the full traceback I get as soon as I press F5 to debug.